# Showing if $f \in R_{\alpha}([a,b])$ $\implies$ $f \in R_{\beta}([a,b])$ where $\beta = V_{a}^{x}(\alpha)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

I am learning about Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals from Carother's Real Analysis. Specifically, I'm trying to learn Riesz Representation. However, prior to that I need to learn the following Theorem:

> Let $\alpha\in BV([a,b])$ and $B(x) = V_{a}^{x}(\alpha).$ Then the following holds: 
>   \begin{align*}
> \Big|\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha\Big| \leq \int_{a}^{b}| f|d\beta \leq ||f||_{\infty}V_{a}^{b}(\alpha)
> \end{align*}

I understand most of the proof but one part of it is not obvious to me. **I don't understand how the author makes the jump from saying $f \in R_{\alpha}([a,b])$ $\implies$ $f \in R_{B}([a,b])$**. I believe they are using the following theorem, but I could be wrong:

> Let $\alpha,\beta \in BV([a,b])$. Then the following holds:
>   \begin{align*}
> f \in R_{\alpha}\cap R_{\beta} \implies f \in R_{\alpha \pm\beta}
> \end{align*}

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks again.

Comment: Are you confused about how to prove that $f \in \mathcal{R}_B([a,b])$ or how to obtain the last inequality? I cover both below. The first part is not conceptually difficult but it involves a lot of technical details and estimates (see my linked answer). The proof of the inequality is where you use that integrability with respect to $\alpha, \beta$ implies integrability with respect to $\alpha \pm \beta$.

Comment: @RRL I was confused about the first part that you have provided in the link. Really appreciate that. The response you gave below was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the function $B$ defined using the total variation of $\alpha$ on the interval $[a,x]$:

$$B(x) = V_a^x(\alpha),$$

it can be shown that $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $B$ and $B - \alpha$. Also if $f$ is integrable then so is $|f|$. A proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2592615/148510).

It appears you understand this fact, and your idea about how to proceed is correct.

To obtain the inequality, take $g = (B+ \alpha)/2$ and $h = (B-\alpha)/2$. Both are increasing functions on $[a,b]$ and using basic properties of Riemann-Stieltjes integration we have

$$\begin{align}\left|\int_a^b f \, d\alpha \right| &= \left|\int_a^b f \, d(g - h)  \right|  \\ &= \left|\int_a^b f \, dg -  \int_a^b f \, dh \right| \\ &\leqslant   \left|\int_a^b f \, dg \right| +  \left|\int_a^b f \, dh \right| \\ &\leqslant \int_a^b |f| \, dg  +  \int_a^b |f| \, dh  \\ & = \int_a^b |f| \, d(g + h) \\ &= \int_a^b |f| \, dB \\ &\leqslant \sup_{t \in [a,b]}|f(t)|(B(b) - B(a)) \\ &= \|f\|_{\infty}V_a^b(\alpha)\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you for your answer this is very clear and understandable.

Comment: @Matthieu: You're welcome.